# add an id when adding rows dynamically

Tags: javascript

how do i add id for each row when im adding the rows dynamically?

I have this so far. I don't know what to do to look for the id. How can I do it this way using clone rather than copying the entire thing and put `i` each time?

```
<table id="attr_add">
               <tr>
                   <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($attr,'['.$i.']name',array('class'=>'span12','placeholder'=>'Red or X-Small')); ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($attr,'['.$i.']cost',array('class'=>'span4','placeholder'=>'89.99')); ?></td>
                   <td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($attr,'['.$i.']value',array('class'=>'span12','placeholder'=>'#ff0000 or Small')); ?></td>
                   <td><input type="button" name="addRow[]" class="removeRow" value='-' />
                  <td> <input type="button" name="addRow[]" class="add" value='+' />
               </tr>
         </table>     

         <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
         var id = 0;
            $(document).on('click', '#attr_add .add', function () {
                id++;

                if(id <7){
                var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                var clone = row.clone();
                var tr = clone.closest('tr');

                tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');
                $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);                  
                }});

            $(document).on('click', '#attr_add .removeRow', function () {
                if ($('#attr_add .add').length > 1) {
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you looking for `tr.id = 'someNewID';`? Not sure what your problem is. I don't understand what *"How can I do it this way using clone rather than copying the entire thing and put i each time?"* is supposed to mean. Which "entire thing"? Put `i` where?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Currently the id for each input is actually blank. Whereas the first one is `id="attr[0]"`, that's because I put it in there. But the in the js, I don't know how I would do `id="attr[1]"`, `id=[2]"` and so forth